# app engine task queue wait limit

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

How long can a task sit in the task queue waiting to be processed before something happens? If its not forever, what are those somethings that might happen?

Can I add a very large number of tasks to a queue that has a very low processing rate and have them be processed over the course of days/weeks/months?

Are tasks ejected from the queue if they're waiting for their turn too long?

[Task Queue Quota and Limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) says

```
maximum countdown/ETA for a task:30 days from the current date and time
```

I think that's talking about intentionally/programatically setting an eta in the future, not how long a task is allowed to wait for its turn.

Comment: btw, creating this scenario on your development machine does not go well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no limit on how many tasks you can have in your queue, other than the amount of storage you have allocated to storing tasks. There's likewise no limit how long they can wait to execute, though as you point out, you can't schedule a task with an ETA more than 30 days in the future.

Comment: There will be a limit on how many tasks you can store, namely 1,000,000 for free accounts. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Task_Queue

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they last forever. I have had some in their for days. Right now I have some that are 9 days old, although the queue is paused. The only limit is the queue size and count ([which are not currently enforced](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Task_Queue)).

Comment: This is the second time I've asked a question and gotten a "from what I can tell" answer in as many days. Not that I don't appreciate the answer; I do, and thanks.

Comment: If there's a limit, it's undocumented and the server-side software isn't open sourced so it's unlikely anyone can answer definitively except Google.

Comment: Hence why its "from what I can tell"